# Finding visitor IP for specific search query

Tags: magento-1.8, database, search-terms

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to find the visitor IP address of a visitor with a specific search query. We have some odd search terms on the site and I know visitors info is stored in log_visitor_info but I am wondering if there is a way I can find out which visitor executed a specific query. Catalogsearch_query shows me the store view, but is there anyway to combine the data to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that you can do this out of box. If you look at `catalogsearch_query`, it doesn't have a column to associate a search query to a visitor.

However, it seems pretty straightforward to implement. I think you'll need to extend `Mage_CatalogSearch`, particularly `Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController::indexAction`, to incorporate the visitor relationship to the query save in this action.

In this action, retrieve the visitor ID/IP and add it to `$query` before the `save()`.